# How to use a horizontal scrollbar (by xpath) - Selenium/Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

The element below is a horizontal scrollbar controlling a small section ("Lines") of an overlay window on a website:

[image]
with the following xpath (it has no other attributes):

```
//div[@class='freeze-pane-scrollbar' and not(@tabindex='-1')]
```

I need to move this scrollbar to the right to access the following element in the table and enter data:

```
(//td[@role='gridcell' and @tabindex='0'])[17]
```

So far I have tried (without luck) using scrollIntoView() and scrollLeft() (possibly due to not being able to use getElementByID)

Comment: if you send a .click() command Selenium should automatically scroll before the click.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very "clean" solution, but I used the following code to achieve what I wanted by clicking with a 400 x-offset from the center of the scrollbar, effectively scrolling it to the right:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
WebElement scrollbar = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='freeze-pane-scrollbar' and not(@tabindex='-1')]"));
builder.moveToElement(scrollbar, 400, 0).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: You're issue may not be that you're not identifying the element right... it might be that the scrollbar sits in an iframe.